# Selenium Getting Started Guide, What did I do Wrong?

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I tried to follow the "[Getting Started Guide](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)" for Selenium as closely as I could, however I get many warnings and errors in console when I try to run the 
code.

 I also imported all of the jars in selenium-java-2.48.2 from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.48/).

 Thank you so much to anyone willing to look through this and try to help me!

 Here are my classes, that I copied and pasted from the guide.


 Example.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the
        // element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

GoogleSuggest.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

            // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
              break;
            }
        }

        // And now list the suggestions
        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
            System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

What appears in the console when I run 'Example.java'

```
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement addBehavior
WARNING: Unimplemented behavior: #default#userdata
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1419] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1467] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1478] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1488] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1499] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1510] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1601] Error in expression. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1613] Error in expression. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1626] Error in expression. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1639] Error in expression. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1653] Error in expression. (Invalid token "}". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:2203] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:2543] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:2616] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:3194] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:3701] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:3761] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:4196] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:4960] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:6103] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:6338] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:6781] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:6938] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:7010] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:7352] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:199] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:1691] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:2949] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:3481] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:3969] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [2:4480] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [3:117] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:685] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Jan 07, 2016 6:15:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.google.com/' [1:1235] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
Page title is: Cheese! - Google Search
```

This class does what its supposed to do, even if it displays a bunch warnings...

 What appears in the console when I run GoogleSuggest.java

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a', time: '2015-10-07 15:45:39'
System info: host: 'Zeus', ip: '192.168.7.103', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=40.0.3, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: f90cec4e-f47c-4306-9491-3248e836dd7c
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=gssb_e}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:467)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:391)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
    at GoogleSuggest.main(GoogleSuggest.java:23)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a', time: '2015-10-07 15:45:39'
System info: host: 'Zeus', ip: '192.168.7.103', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6644175254170304178webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6644175254170304178webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6644175254170304178webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6644175254170304178webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous6644175254170304178webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Along with all that in the console, the class also opens FireFox, waits for Google to load, types cheese, searches, and then stops and all the errors appear.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings observed when running `Example.java` can be ignored and the code is working fine. If you wish to remove the warning you can do so by adding the following lines of code.

```
public class Example {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.setLevel(Level.OFF)
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        ...................................
        ...................................
        ...................................
    }
}
```

There is a couple of problems I observed with `GoogleSuggest.java`.

1. The code written for `Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over` is wrong. According to your code, Selenium will look for the element untill `System.currentTimeMillis()` is less than `end`. But each time selenium looks for the div, an Exception saying the element is not found is thrown. This should be handled in a try catch.
2. The `resultsDiv` is identified using class name `gssb_e` in your code. When I checked I got class name as `sbsb_a`. Please check this.
3. The `list` is obtained by xpath `//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']` in your code. When I checked there is no `td` tag which is relevent. Try the following xpath `//div[@class='sbqs_c']`.

The summary of code changes required:

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    try {
        WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("sbsb_a"));

        // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a
        // drop down.
        if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing 
    }
}

// And now list the suggestions
List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! This was super helpful!

Comment: Hi ,Which package i need to select because i'm getting error like getLogger is not a method or not available etc message,please help how to resolve the issue

Comment: @RajeshOm If I remember correctly, it is java.util.logging

Answer (score 1):

It just warnings, you can ignore them.

Use another WEB driver instead of default. For instance it could be CHROME (you can chose between different browsers like CHROME, FIREFOX_31, FIREFOX_31, INTERNET_EXPLORER_8, INTERNET_EXPLORER_11 ).

HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
I suppose it should fix your problem.